# Environment variable is showing blank after user logout

Tags: linux, unix, redhat, hana, sap-basis

I have been trying to set below environment variable for a user, but once I set this variable, source the file and logout the user session the environment variable is showing blank

```
dbs_hdb_connect=ENCRYPT=TRUE,sslCryptoProvider=commoncrypto,sslKeyStore=/usr/sap/<SID>/HDBxx/<hostname>/sec/SAPSSLC.pse,sslTrustStore=/usr/sap/<SID>/HDBxx/<hostname>/sec/SAPSSLC.pse
```

After logging out and log back into the user session the env variable is showing blank, is it something to do with the character length?

```
admin1> env | grep dbs_hdb_connect_property=
```

I tried below scenario to confirm the issue, I adjusted the env variable name length and got below results. only "dbs_hdb_connect_property" is showing blank all other are working fine.

Content of .sapenv.sh file as follows:-

```
export dbs_hdb_connect_p="test"
export dbs_hdb_connect_proper="test"
export dbs_hdb_connect_propert="test"
export dbs_hdb_connect_pro="test"
export dbs_hdb_connect_prop="test"
export dbs_hdb_connect_pr="test"
export dbs_hdb_connect="test"
export dbs_hdb_connect_prope="test"
export dbs_hdb_connect_property="test"

source .sapenv.sh
```

And after this I logged out of the user, logged back in and fired below command to check if the env variables populated. But as you can see "dbs_hdb_connect_property" is empty and others are populated.

```
admin1> env | grep dbs
```

```
dbs_hdb_connect_p=test
dbs_hdb_connect_proper=test
dbs_hdb_connect_propert=test
dbs_hdb_connect_pro=test
dbs_hdb_connect_prop=test
dbs_hdb_connect_pr=test
dbs_hdb_connect=test
dbs_hdb_connect_prope=test
dbs_hdb_connect_property=
```

I was setting the env variable permanently by mentioning the variable in .sapenv.sh file (This is similar to bashrc but for SAP application). The shell being used here is /bin/sh. And I am setting the variable for only one user.  My point is even if I mention this variable in bashrc or profile it's not loading. When I export it manually from command line it will load but as soon as I logout of that session it goes blank from next login. So, I am wondering is there any limit here for setting the variable name too long?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How exactly do you set the variable? By typing it in a shell? Do you want to set it for one specific user or for all users? What shell(s) do you use?

Comment: I was setting them permanently by mentioning the variable in .sapenv.sh file (This is similar to bashrc but for SAP application). The shell being used here is /bin/sh. And I am setting the variable for only one user.

Comment: Does the file `.sapenv.sh` get sourced somewhere? Does the script `export` the variable?

Comment: Yes The way I mentioned the env variables in .sapenv.sh is same as that we mention in bashrc pr .profile. This how it looks like 

export dbs_hdb_connect_property="ENCRYPT=TRUE,sslCryptoProvider=commoncrypto,sslKeyStore=/usr/sap/<SID>/HDBxx/<hostname>/sec/SAPSSLC.pse,sslTrustStore=/usr/sap/<SID>/HDBxx/<hostname>/sec/SAPSSLC.pse"

Comment: **Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification**, don't use comments for this purpose. Code is hard to read in comments. How is the file `.sapenv.sh` executed? Do you manually run `. .sapenv.sh`? Is something like this in some `.bash*` or `.profile` file? Does a script to start the program read or run this file? Do you have  `source .sapenv.sh` in `.sapenv.sh`? A recursive call of the same file is wrong. You wrote that you use `/bin/sh` (not `bash`). In this case you should use `.` instead of `source`. (`source` is an alias for `.` in `bash` and some other shells.)

Comment: I don't know the naming pattern in redhat, but is `dbs_hdb_connect` var from your snippet is the same as **dbs**dbs_hdb_connect_property? are you sure you set this same var in the beginning?

Comment: That was just a typo, I have edited the question, but my point is even if I mention this variable in bashrc or profile it's not loading. When I export it it will load but as soon as I logout of that session it goes blank from next login. So I am wondering is there any limit here for setting the variable name too long?